# How can I pipe the filename into an ffmpeg command?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, terminal

I would like to run this command in the terminal:
`ffmpeg -i <input-file> -ac 2 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 48k -ar 16000 <output-file.mp3>` on every `mp3` file in a folder.

The input and output could be the same (an overwrite), but if this is not possible, if there was a way to take the filename and append `_converted` maybe?

I'm not a bash expert, but I know that I need to pipe the results of an `ls` command into the ffmpeg command using a variable perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With xargs:

```
printf "%s\0" * | xargs -0 -I {} ffmpeg -i {} -ac 2 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 48k -ar 16000 converted_{}
```

---

See: `man xargs`

Comment: `ffmpeg` reads from stdin, so if `xargs` doesn't read (/buffer) the entire file list before running `ffmpeg` for the first time, `ffmpeg` may steal part of the file list. Some versions of `xargs` have a `-o` option that fixes this, but not all.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Thank you for pointing that out. Unfortunately this is the case here. I removed option `-y` (overwrite) and added a prefix for converted files.

Comment: Looks like the output needs to be a different file too. The results are all just a second long.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - your answer is a bash script correct? I just wanted a command in the terminal that I could run and pipe from stdin to the ffmpeg command.

Comment: Shame you deleted it. Still a great answer, and useful.

Comment: @LeeProbert, I thought it is not useful for you do deleted it. Have done undo now, Cheers.

Comment: @LeeProbert: you can use RavinderSingh13's answer as oneliner, too: `for file in *.mp3; do output_file="${file%.mp3}_converted.mp3"; ffmpeg -i "$file" -ac 2 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 48k -ar 16000 "$output_file"; done`

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, since I don't have ffpmeg command so couldn't test it. This should save output into same Input_file itself, better to test it on a test folder and once happy with results could run on actual folder.

```
for file in *.mp3
do
   ffmpeg -i "$file" -ac 2 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 48k -ar 16000 "temp" && mv "temp" "$file"
done
```

OR as per OP you want to take output `_converted` string into output file name then try following.

```
for file in *.mp3
do
   output_file="${file}_converted"
   ffmpeg -i "$file" -ac 2 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 48k -ar 16000 "$output_file"
done
```

OR as per @Gordon Davisson sir's comment use following.

```
for file in *.mp3
do
   output_file="${file%.mp3}_converted.mp3"
   ffmpeg -i "$file" -ac 2 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 48k -ar 16000 "$output_file"
done
```

Comment: `"$file_converted"` will look for a  variable named `file_converted` -- use `"${file}_converted"` instead, or better yet `output_file="${file%.mp3}_converted.mp3"` to keep the extension at the end.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, Thank you sir for letting know, I edited my post and added your suggestion's code too now, cheers .